# Wordpress site in subdirectory load site in main directory

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have two wordpress site one in main directory (public_html) and another one is in subdirectory staging. I already configure all the settings in subdirectory site with http://example.com/staging but when I load http://example.com/staging it redirect to Page Not Found in main site and not in staging site. I set the .htaccess file in staging subdirectory like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this in on the main site in main directory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Anybody can help me with this issue and my staging site can load properly ? Thank you before.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can try:

- Check the wp-options table in your staging site database and look for
  site URL in 2 places. Change it to the correct staging address if already not.
- Refresh the permalinks of the staging site.

I am guessing this should fix your problem. If not, please share your website address.

P.S. If both the sites (main and stage) have the same content, you might wanna add a robots.txt file in the staging instance just to be safe from being considered as duplicate content.

Comment: I already change site URL and home with correct url in wp-options and how to refresh permalinks if I cannot open and login to wordpress dashboard ?

Comment: And for the main and staging yes it's have same content. How to add robots.txt file in staging ?

Comment: ok. lets worry about the robots file later. Check your wp-config.php file for correct DB details. What is the result of example.com/staging/wp-login.php? Is it redirecting to the main domain?

Comment: Yes in wp-config.php the DB details is correct. And, example.com/staging/wp-login.php yes it gives me redirecting to the main domain page not found.

Comment: ok try this one, open the index.php for your staging site (the one inside WordPress not in theme folder), find the line require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' ); and change it to require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/staging/wp-blog-header.php' );
Let me know the results.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try moving your staging instance from a subdirectory to subdomain. something like staging.example.com. This is a lot easy to setup.

Comment: I change like this `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/staging/wp-blog-header.php' );` but still gives redirect to main site page not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69151/discussion-between-sid-and-antonio).

Comment: I tried to use subdomain but it's give me domain not register